# how to get details in html tags using preg_match_all

Tags: php

I'm using `preg_match_all` function to grab details on a web page. But problem is it returns exact matches to the given structure.

Example:

```
<span class="st">Details I want to get</span>
```

But actually it looks like:

```
<span class="st"><em>Details </em>I want to <b>get<b></span>
```

So it returns just a few results that exactly match the above given first code!

I found an article about grabbing & there was a code and is it possible to do this using a code like this because I found this working with above structure?

```
$nodes = $xPath->query('//span[@class="st"]');
foreach($nodes as $node) {
    echo $node->nodeValue, PHP_EOL;
}
```

Comment: Stackoverflow isn't well suited for tutoring. Phrases like "help me" with redundant exclamation marks aren't useful. -- Regarding your topic, research xpath. Or for simplicity use [phpQuery or QueryPath](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3659729/345031).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use php DOMDocument and strip_tags

```
$xml = '<span class="st">Details i want to get</span>';
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadXML($xml);
$spans = $dom->getElementsByTagName('span');
foreach ($spans as $span) {
 // you can check class etc with conditional statements
  #strip_tags to remove <em> and other tags inside that tag
  echo strip_tags($span->nodeValue), PHP_EOL;
}
```

Comment: how to combine $xml values with the results im getting through my code?
    $ch = curl_init($gg_url.$page.'0');
    curl_setopt_array($ch,$options);
    $scraped="";
    $scraped.=curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close( $ch );
    $results = array();

Comment: i didnt get you, elaborate more

Comment: i use $ch = curl_init($gg_url.$page.'0'); curl_setopt_array($ch,$options); $scraped=""; $scraped.=curl_exec($ch); curl_close( $ch ); $results = array(); code to grab all the contents on a specific page($gg_url) after that i use     preg_match_all('/a href="([^"]+)" class=l.+?>.+?<\/a>/',$scraped,$results);   to get the URLs on that page like wise is there any way to combine ur code to my code to get contents in <span class="st">. im new to php thats y!

Comment: $xml= the string which you returned form $gg_url

Comment: I tried to do like that before ! but a warning displays --- Warning: DOMDocument::loadXML() [domdocument.loadxml]: Start tag expected, '<' not found in Entity, line: 1 in /home/yalumalu/public_html/z/index.php on line 131